# CLion on mac: configure package path

Tags: c++, ide, clion

I have some C++ project and I imported into CLion. Now in the header files if I have this line it doesn't work:

```
#include "myproject/some_header_file.h"
```

If I change that to the following it works:

```
#include "../some_header_file.h"
```

This is really strange to me, anybody knows how to config the IDE to make it work using the first line? Otherwise I need to change all the places to make it work...

Thanks!

Comment: `#include "..."` form accepts paths relative the location of the current file and fallbacks to the known include dirs if file at the relative path is missing. So the second form is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your include path on CLion using the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Just write `include_directories(.)` inside your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Note that `#include` to directories in your include path is done using `<>` insted of `""`.

Like so:
`#include <myproject/some_header_file.h>`